# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Translation' of undefined, Does anyone tell me what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I get this error every time I try to execute my angular code

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Translation' of undefined
```

Models 
in the model the array that is sent to the component is constructed

```
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

export class TranslationsMessagge {

    constructor( ) {
    }

    public translations() {

        //filtraremos el idioma
        switch (environment.language) {
            //Español
            case 1:
                this.translation.Translation().subscribe(data => {
                    if (data) {
                        let translation: any = data;
                        translation = translation.body;
                        let tempArr: any = [];
                        $.each(translation.body.es, (i: any, item: { id: string; m: string; }) => {
                            tempArr.push({ id: item.id, m: item.m });
                        });
                        return tempArr;
                    }
                })
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

component

here in the component I just try to show what I bring from the model

```
//Traducciones
import { TranslationService } from '../../services/translation/translation.service';
import { TranslationsMessagge } from '../../models/translations/translations.message.model';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    public  msg:TranslationsMessagge;
    constructor(private router: Router, private translations: TranslationService) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('bit_token') != null) {
            this.router.navigate(['Dashboard']);
        this.msg= new TranslationsMessagge();
    }
   ngOnInit() {
        console.log( this.msg.translations() ); 
    }
```

I need to know why I get that error, I'm looking for and I'm looking for a solution and nothing I find helps please. 
I really need it, what's wrong?

Comment: Just a quick guess? `this.translation` in TranslationsMessagge is undefined, but it's not even be declared in your class. The code you've provided appears to be incomplete.

Comment: it doesn't let me put more code because it exceeds a lot

Comment: You haven't declare this.translation that's why it gives undefined